# Sharepoint WSPBuilder Feature Update

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, wspbuilder

I have two webparts that currently have the default "MyGroup" property in the elements.xml file.  I'm simply trying to change these values to something more descriptive by updating both the Group and QuickAddGroups property values; rebuildng my dll, uninstalling from WSPBuilder and then re-deploying (using WSPBuilder).  However, this does not seem to work.  I still see the old property group listed.  I've also tried manually deleting the webpart from the webpart gallery page to no avail.  What do I need to do?  Is there an stsadm command that I should run, perhaps -uninstallfeature or -deactiveatefeature?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making sure you get it right the first time, manually deleting the web part from the gallery is probably your best option.

If that doesn't work, it may just be the ordering - try deactivate the feature, delete the web part, then activate it again. Also check that the elements.xml in the 12 hive contains what you expect - occasionally these things refuse to update for no apparent reason.